# List names of all available MS SQL databases on server using python

Tags: python, sql-server, database, sqlalchemy, pymssql

Trying to list the names of the databases on a remote MS SQL server using Python (Just like the Object Explorer in MS SQL Server Management Studio).

**Current solution**: The required query is `SELECT name FROM sys.databases;`. So current solution is using SQLAlchemy and Pandas, which works fine as below.

```
import pandas    
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
#database='master'
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://user:password@server:port/master')
query = "select name FROM sys.databases;"
data = pandas.read_sql(query, engine)
```

output:

```
                  name
0               master
1               tempdb
2                model
3                 msdb
```

**Question:** How to list the names of the databases on the server using
SQLAlchemy's `inspect(engine)` similar to listing table names under a database? Or any simpler way without importing Pandas?

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect

#trial 1: with no database name
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://user:password@server:port')
#this engine not have DB name
inspector = inspect(engine)
inspector.get_table_names() #returns []
inspector.get_schema_names() #returns [u'dbo', u'guest',...,u'INFORMATION_SCHEMA']

#trial 2: with database name 'master', same result
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://user:password@server:port/master')
inspector = inspect(engine)
inspector.get_table_names() #returns []
inspector.get_schema_names() #returns [u'dbo', u'guest',...,u'INFORMATION_SCHEMA']
```

Comment: They should exist in `inspector.get_table_names()`; have you tried `print(inspector.get_table_names())`?

Comment: Thanks! Already tried. This does return table names under a DB name, but not the DB names in the server.

Comment: D'oh! I clearly have my brain shut off during this holiday week, and misread the question entirely. I'm guessing in SQL Server `get_schema_names()` wouldn't work, since you'd just get a list of `dbo`s? It is worth a shot; I don't have my SQL Server rig handy, or I'd do some testing (off of work this week).

Comment: get_schema_names() returns identical results for two different servers. So guessing that it shows the default building blocks of the servers, not the in-house DB names that I want. Edited the question with more info

Comment: I think you meant `get_schema_names` instead of `get_table_names` in your code block?

Comment: No it is right. Did not show get_schema_names() output. Now now added them as well. But none of get_schema_names and get_table_names yield required info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you really want to do is avoid importing pandas then the following works fine for me:

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://sa:saPassword@localhost:52865/myDb')
conn = engine.connect()
rows = conn.execute("select name FROM sys.databases;")
for row in rows:
    print(row["name"])
```

producing

```
master
tempdb
model
msdb
myDb
```

Comment: Thanks! engine.connect().execute(...) works, even when port and DB name are not rovided in create_engine()!

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to obtain tables from a specific scheme with execute the single query with the driver below: `DB-API interface to Microsoft SQL Server for Python`.

```sh
pip install pymssql
```

```py
import pymssql

# Connect to the database
conn = 
pymssql.connect(server='127.0.0.1',user='root',password='root',database='my_database')

# Create a Cursor object
cur = conn.cursor()

# Execute the query: To get the name of the tables from my_database
cur.execute("select table_name from information_schema.tables") # where table_schema = 'tableowner'
    for row in cur.fetchall():

# Read and print tables
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row[0])
```

output:

```sh
my_table_name_1
my_table_name_2
my_table_name_3
...
my_table_name_x
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following snippet will list the names of the available databases on whatever server you choose to connect to.  This will return a JSON object that will be displayed in your browser.  This question is a bit old, but I hope this helps anyone curious who stops by.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
from flask_jsonpify import jsonify

engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://user:password@server:port/master')

class AllTables(Resource):
    def get(self):
        conn = engine.connect()
        inspector = inspect(conn)
        tableList = [item for item in inspector.get_table_names()]
        result = {'data': tableList}
        return jsonify(result)

api.add_resource(AllTables, '/alltables')

app.run(port='8080')
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution which fetch row by row:

```
import pymssql
connect = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, database)
cursor = connect.cursor(as_dict=True)
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    for r in row.items():
        print r[0], r[1]
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```